# Laravel 4 Authentication attempt() fails

Tags: authentication, laravel-4

I have a problem with Laravel authentication system:

```
$credentials = array(
    'email' => Input::get('email'),
    'password' => Input::get('password'),
    'active' => 1
);

if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
    echo "fine";
}else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

`Auth::attempt()`always return false.

Therefore, I tried to authenticate an other  way:

```
$user = User::where('email','=',Input::get('email'))->firstOrFail();
if ($user->active && Hash::check(Input::get('password'), $user->password)){
    echo "fine";
}else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

This one works.

Would you know what could possibly make the `attempt` method not working?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but I think you have edited User model ( check if you still implement UserInterface and RemindableInterface for exemple)

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/models/User.php